# Copy to last row three worksheets same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook named SHRP Control Compare.xlsx with three tabs. Tab 1 is SHRP, 2 is SharePoint Control and the last tab is Results. When I copy the from SHRP to Results next I need to copy from SharePoint Control to the next available row in the Results tab. I have tried multiple last row methods can't get it to work. if someone can point me the right direction Appreciate it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What was not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Sub copypaste()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, lr As Long
Set wb = Workbooks("SHRP Control Compare Results.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("SharePoint Control")
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:J600")
lr = Sheets("Results").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
rng.Copy Destination:=ws.Range("B" & lr)
Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).